# Issue to enter in a condition function

Tags: javascript, django

In the interactive shell of Django, I got

```
In [1]: contract = Contract.objects.get(pk=2)

In [2]: contract
Out[2]: <Contract: Contract with David Bouchard (en)>

In [3]: contract.request.customer.convert_fax_number
Out[3]: ''
```

In a JavaScript function, I created a variable `var fax_number = "{{ contract.request.customer.convert_fax_number }}";` and create the following if condition function

```
  if (fax_number == '') {
        alert('Please, attach the fax number to your profile');
        return;
    }
```

I put a breakpoint of the first line of that code. Hence, I know that the compiler stopped on this line, but it has never executed the statement of that if condition.

Here is the whole function :

```
(function($){

  var bindEvents = function(node){
    $('.btn-fax', node).bind('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = {};
      var fax_number = "{{ contract.request.customer.convert_fax_number }}";
      $.ajax({
        url : $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'POST',
        data : data,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          if (data.success) {
              if (data.redirect_to) {
                window.location.href = data.redirect_to;
              }
              else if (data.reload) {
                window.location.reload();
              }
          }
          else {
            alert('Error! See console for details :(');
            console.error(textStatus, data);
          }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (fax_number == '') {
                alert('Please, attach the fax number to your profile');
                return;
            }
            console.error(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  };
```

and here the modification I did to convert unicode string to simple string :

```
@property
def convert_fax_number(self):
    fax = self.fax
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', fax).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

It's not working even it the output of `convert_fax_number` is a simple empty string `''`. How could I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That property is nonsense, and there is no reason to "convert unicode string to simple string".

Comment: I understand @DanielRoseman, but even if a replace `convert_fax_number` to `fax` (output is `u''`),  `alert('Please, attach the fax number to your profile');` is never called. I just can't solve that problem. I  need a bit of help here.

Comment: Then you should use console.log() or alert() to find out what the value actually is. Why are you only checking that inside the Ajax error function, anyway?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry, but I do not have a lot of experience with js. Could you tell me if the variable `fax_number` is well defined? If I put `console.log(fax_number)`, the output is simply `{{ contract.request.customer.convert_fax_number }}`, and if I remove the quote I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`.

Answer (score 0):

First of remember to use triple equals `===` when comparing strings to make sure that it's not doing weird asumptions.

Can you do a `console.log('whatever')` in the line on top of the `if` statement just to make sure that it's executing the `error` function? although I know that you said:

> I know that the compiler stopped on this line

It's better to be completely sure.

Then, you should try with a `console.log(fax_number == '')` and `console.log(fax_number === '')` to see what's happening just below the variable declaration. Let me know what you find out.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not being rendered by Django - presumably it is in a separate JavaScript file, not in a Django template. You'll need to pass the value into your JS from the actual template itself.

Comment: Could you clearly explain how I could do such thing with an example? I would appreciate.